# Processing tool to invert/switch selection in Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis-3, select-by-attribute, qgis-modeler

I want to switch/invert a selection in Graphical Modeler so I'm looking for a processing tool to do so. In ArcGIS, this can be done with `"Select Layer By Attribute"` with `Selection type: SWITCH_SELECTION`.

Can the same be done in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use "select by expression" tool and insert `if(is_selected() is false,true,false)` as expression. This will allow inverting your selection in graphical modeler.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: You can even simplify the expression to `NOT is_selected()`.